# Django Relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new at Django and have a few problems getting my mind around manytomany relatiosnhips and Manytoone (i.e Foreign key).

My setup is this.

I have class A, Class B, Class C

Every Class B object must belong to a Class A object. They cannot belong to more than one Class A object. A more practical example could be if Class A is a Music Band and class B is a song with that Band. Most Bands will have more than one song but every song must belong to a Band (in this example a song can never have multiple Bands).

Class C is a listing of individual Band members. So every band member can be associated with an arbitrary number of songs as well as an arbitrary number of Bands. In other words a member of Band X can also be a member of Band Y.

My question then would be

How would i use the ForeignKey and ManytoMany relationships in this context?

This example is contrived just to make my situation easier to understand and to help me explain my issue. I would like the admin to display for each Class C object what Class B objects or Class A objects that Class C belongs go. The same goes for Class B and Class A.

If you look at Class A objects you should be able to se a listing of all Class B objects that belong to that particular Class A object.

Any and all input appreciated.

Comment: Manytoone?  Is that somewhere in Scotland?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I'd set it up (in your `models.py`)

```
class Member(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ...

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name


class Band(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   members = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
   ... 

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   band = models.ForeignKey(Band)
   ...

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

Set up like this:

- `member.band_set.all()` gives you all bands a member belongs to
- `band.members.all()` gives you the members of a band
- `song.band` gives you the band for that song
- `band.song_set.all()` gives you all songs for a band

Note that the `band_set` on member and the `song_set` on band are "reverse" relationships. They aren't explicitly defined in the models, but Django sets them up for you transparently. You can customize these by using the `related_name` parameter on the field definition. Example:

```
class Band(models.Model):
   members = models.ManyToManyField(Member,related_name='bands')
```

would let you get all the bands for a member as follows:

```
member.bands.all()
```

The admin will automatically provide the following:

- Show all members for a band in a multi-select list
- Show the band for a song in a single select list

However, if you want to see songs for a band, you'll have to do a little admin customization.

In your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class SongInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Song
    extra = 1

class BandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SongInline]

admin.site.register(Band,BandAdmin)
admin.site.register(Member)
admin.site.register(Song)
```

This will let you view the songs right from the admin page -- and edit or add them as well! By following this template you could show all bands for a member as well.

You can get a more detailed introduction to the admin customization at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Thanks, the answers are coming in so fast I havent been able to catch up :).
I shall give it whirl and see if I can get it to work with your suggestions.

Comment: Hi again, it seems to work - allthough in Band it onlky displays a "memmber object" and not the name of the member. I know I can do a list_display but I don not know how to set a list_display on memebr of another class. i.e in class BandAdmin using list_display = ('Member.firstname', 'Memeber.lastname') does not work, and if I set a class MemberAdmin with the above mentioned list_display it get a list display in the Memeber viw, but the list in Band view still only displays a "Member Object" but not the name of the member. I'm sure this is trivial but would appreciate a helping hand on this

Comment: I've modified the code to do what you want. If you don't define a __unicode__ method on the class, you get the default string representation of the class ("member object"). My __unicode__ methods all return the object's name -- so with that change you should see the name of the band, song, etc.

Comment: I managed to solve it myself. Once again. Many thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is all fairly straightforward. I've used the descriptive names below, to make it easier to follow.

```
class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BandMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bands = models.ManyToManyField(Band)

class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band)

# get a band
myband = Band.objects.get(name='myband')

# all songs from that band
print myband.song_set.all()

# all members of that band
print myband.bandmembers.all()


# get a specific band member
dave = BandMember.objects.get(name='Dave')

# what bands is Dave a member of?
print dave.bands.all()

# what songs has Dave sung? (slightly more complicated)
print Song.objects.get(band__bandmember=dave)
```

Comment: +1 - Great answer - might be worth editing why you've got `ManyToManyField('Band')` but `ForeignKey(Band)`, because at present it looks like that's the way you have to define `ManyToManyField` and `ForeignKey` respectively, rather than to do with the order in which the classes were defined.

Comment: Good point, I've actually reordered the classes so there's no need to use the string form.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the response. I understand your answer, but the issue at the moment is the admin page. If i enter a new BandMember i am prompted to say what Songs he is connected to. And if i open a band member I can se a drop list that seems to contain the id of every song.
If i enter a bandmember (which has a particular id nr - which can also be found in the song table) once its created when one looks at the band memeber the admin should display this. Do I have to create special views for admin to do this?